# How can I repair my leaking/dripping tap?

Tags: plumbing, leak, plumbing-fixture

Our tap is leaking. It started with a drip but occasionally it's a continuous flow. It's the cold tap (right). I've taken off the lever to reveal the small cog that controls the flow; no obvious damage there. None of the teeth appear to be broken.

What I've noticed is that, if I push the tap handle towards the left (in the direction of the actual goose-neck faucet) the drip stops. My temporary solution, a rubber band:

[image: Temporary fix for tap]

Although I'm pretty proud of myself, I'd prefer to get to the root of the problem. I've read online that inside the tap there's some sort of cartridge that can sometimes be the issue. Given the problem and the temporary solution, is this likely to be the source of the issue? And if it is, how do I ensure I replace it with the correct cartridge? If it isn't the cartridge, what else could it be?

If it's not already obvious; I'm no plumber.

Comment: At its simplest, you will need a replacement washer. I'd hesitate to advise you DIY this, I'd call the plumber. If you see this done once, you'll be better-armed to tackle it yourself in future.

Comment: Disassembling the faucet to get to the cartridge is _generally_ a DIY project if you've got a few basic tools or are willing to get some. I would point out, though, that if you are renting (not obvious one way or the other), this is generally something that the landlord/management company should be responsible for - give them a call.